# With Notepad++ how can I change the vertical outline color?

Tags: notepad++, theming

What is the setting in Notepad++ for changing the outline color?  In the attached image I want to change the vertical red line to a different color.  Thank you!

[image]

This is the theme file that I'm trying to adjust.  That red color is the standard #ff0000, which isn't in the XML template.
https://github.com/SeanCline/Npp-VS2012-Dark

Comment: How did you install the theme? I can't find the theme folder, and when I import it from NP++ , it doesn't appear.

Comment: @aCodingN00b, Copy the theme file to your %PROGRAMFILES%\Notepad++\themes (or for 64 bit the %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Notepad++\themes) directory.  Then open Notepad++ and select Settings > Style Configurator > Language HTML, and in the "Select theme" dropdown choose "VS2012-Dark". Then select the "Save & Close" button.

Comment: I don't see the themes/ folder in my Notepad++ directory.

Comment: It was int the AppData/Roaming/Notepad++ folder.

Answer (score 0):

That's the foreground color of Global Styles > Fold. What you are referring to is a code folding section.

Comment: Hmm, -1 for taking 2 minutes to answer this.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock. That's close, but didn't get the vertical line. I changed Global Styles > Fold > Foreground Color, and that just impacted a small horizontal line that extends off the vertical line.  And Fold > Background colour just gets the [+] [-] boxes.

Comment: @Ken Palmer: Ahhh, I see what you mean. You're specifically talking about the fold that's highlighted wherever the current line of code is. Turns out there's a "Fold active" option which for some reason isn't present in the majority of the default Notepad++ styles. Probably a new feature. I wonder if you have to add it into the style XML file manually.

Comment: Okay, well that puts me on the right track then.  We just extracted that color, and it's plain old #ff0000, which doesn't show up in my XML theme file.  I'll put a link to that file in the OP for reference.